# Control position of new Veusz window

Tags: python, veusz

This question is about [Veusz](http://home.gna.org/veusz), a python-based plotting program. Not about usage, but about where to start hacking to fix a particular problem... This is on Windows.

Currently, when the program is launched it starts non-maximized, even if it was maximized last time it was closed. I can modify the shortcut to always start maximized but new windows opened within the app are always non-maximized.

Although it doesn't remember its maximized state, it does remember the size of last non-maximized window. As a workaround, I tried positioning the program top-left and resizing it as if it were maximized. However, when I open new windows from this one, they are offset from the top-left corner by the height of the "window bar". The offset does not cascade though; that is, opening a new window from an offset one results in a window in the same position.

I've been pawing through the program's files looking for somewhere window position might be saved or a default might be set. Not seeing anything, though. This is a Qt app so perhaps it's not Veusz-specific but I'm inclined to think it is. Spyder, for instance is Qt-based but I don't see this problem with it.

Does the community have any suggestions regarding changing this behavior? I don't understand the setup routine well enough yet. The source is [on Github](https://github.com/jeremysanders/veusz) if you're feeling that helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is here in functions `closeEvent` (for saving state) and `setupWindowGeometry` (for loading state).
https://github.com/jeremysanders/veusz/blob/master/veusz/windows/mainwindow.py

Veusz needs to save the state of the window, as well as the geometry. Maybe doing something like this http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/restoring-geometry.html

Comment: I have seen this in a few other Qt apps now but this is an excellent answer. Thanks.